# How to reference the Request object from a linked DLL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My company has a variety of software products which have the ability to record an IP address. Each product does this differently, be it via `HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress` or some sort of server variable (`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, or `REMOTE_ADDR`) or one or two other ways.

We recently moved data centers, and our 3 web servers are in a load balancer. Most of these solutions now record the load balancer's IP address instead of the actual end user's IP. According to my research, the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` should give us the desired IP (once we configure IIS / the load balancer correctly).

I created a DLL which I'd like to plug into the rest of our applications:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyIpReader
{
    public class IpReader : Controller
    {
        public string GetXForwardIp()
        {
            if (Request == null || Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] == null)
                return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

            return Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I added this DLL to one of our projects and run it, but the `Request` object is always `null` so it ends up returning the `UserHostAddress`.

Why is this, and more importantly how can I fix it?

If it matters: my `MyIpReader` project is .NET 4.5 and the `System.Web.Mvc` DLL says `Runtime Version v4.0.30319` and the actual `Version` property itself is `5.2.3.0`

Answer (score 2):

**Request** must be evaluated in the context of the web request.

I sueest you this solution:

```
namespace MyIpReader
{
    public class IpReader : Controller
    {
        private string HttpRequest request;

        public IpReader(HttpRequest request) 
        {
            this.request = request;
        }

        public string GetXForwardIp()
        {
            if (this.request == null || this.request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] == null)
                return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

            return this.request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to make a few tweaks to your solution: `private string HttpRequest` should be `private HttpRequestBase`, and the constructor argument should also be a `HttpRequestBase` type. I was hoping to avoid the need to pass in an object to this DLL (just because I'm not certain our older applications will be able to support this) but oh well. Thanks